# Как установить, открыть и работать на JAVA?

Tags: установка, java

Как установить, открыть и работать на JAVA?

Comment: Надо хотя бы из уважения к участникам форума заполнить собсно тело вопроса...

Answer (score 4):

- Скачать [jdk](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) на сайте oracle. Можно 1.6, можно 1.7. JRE качать не нужно, он есть частью jdk.
- Скачать ide под java (например eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA, netbeans) или воспользоваться блокнотом(блокнотозаменителем). Все очень легко гуглится.

Все в принципе бесплатно и мультиплатформенно (idea есть в community версии, которой хватит с головой).

Comment: Еще добавлю: купить несколько книжек по Java и учиться, учиться, учиться.

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне то проще сначала бы пересмотреть некоторые видеоматериалы (это не значит что нужно отбросить книжную инфу)

видеоуроки можно взять    [здесь](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3339945), или если эти не подходят то погуглить, етово в нете полно.

**лично мое мнение,** для того чтобы работать с java нужно иметь опыт с программированием консольных приложений (Borland Pascal, Turbo C++), лучше Java в консольном режиме, но повторяю КАК АН МЕНЯ, было бы лучше начать с Паскаля.

После этого надо хорошо освоить основные приципи ООП, и браться за работу с Delphi (лучше NET beans)

И уже третим шагом можно браться за Eclipse, где практически весь код вводит программист (я имею в виду создание и задание параметров визуальных элементов).

**Повторяю еще раз эти три шага я описал исходя из своего опыта и хода мышления.**

И еще одно на прохождение этого пути нужно не один месяц, возможно даже год, поэтому если беретесь за это дело советую запастись **терпением и настойчивостью**. Удачи

Comment: Паскаль - время на помойку. Из своего опыта: лучше начать с С. Простой, логичный, лаконичный язык, ничего лишнего, в меру низкоуровневый, поэтому хорошо усваиваются понятия принципах работы компьютера вообще. Потом можно сразу на ООП: С++ или Java. Сначала блокнот+консоль. Потом можно и на IDE разных поработать.

Comment: Паскаль я предложил только потому, что он идет для начинающих практически во всех учебных программах вузов, и я с него начинал также.

На счет С ++ я полностью с вами согласен, с него гораздо проще переходить на JAVA, ибо она есть С подобной.

Comment: Ну да, почему-то у нас традиция -начинать обучение программированию с Паскаля. Хотя, я думаю, этот подход уже устарел. Хотя бы с Дельфи начинали, что-ли. И то польза от этого больше.